# Sporadic write failures with UnauthorizedException: Unable to perform authorization of super-user permission: Cannot achieve consistency level QUORUM

Tags: cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm using Apache Spark to write data to a Cassandra cluster. The deployment is kubernetes based and am using cassandra helm chart. Sporadically, I encounter a SparkException that leads to job abortion, as detailed below:

> Caused by: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.UnauthorizedException: Unable to perform
> authorization of permissions: Unable to perform authorization of super-user permission: Cannot
> achieve consistency level QUORUM

Additional details on the Cassandra cluster:

Datacenter: datacenter1

```
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address        Load       Tokens  Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  10.x.x.x  10.98 GiB  256     64.7%             blahblah-c2e0509a03                        rack1
UN  10.x.x.x  12.17 GiB  256     69.7%             blahblah-a617-4dfbcdb999aa                 rack1
UN  10.x.x.x  12.6 GiB   256     65.6%             blahblah-9d4f-9111f4ae55a3
```

I have already ensured that the system_auth keyspace is replicated to all these nodes. However, the issue still appears intermittently. I'd appreciate any insight into why this might be happening and how to potentially resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

It mentions super-user, are you using user cassandra by chance?
User cassandra with authenticate at QUORUM, so it makes that operation more expensive, all other users will authenticate at LOCAL_ONE.
If you happen to be using cassandra, then create a new super user and use the user-created one instead.
If you aren't using user cassandra, then consider increasing the role/permission/credential cache settings in the cassandra.yaml, those parameters are mentioned here:
https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/3.11/cassandra/configuration/cass_yaml_file.html#roles_validity_in_ms

Answer (score 1):

The `UnauthorizedException` is propagated by the Cassandra Java driver that is embedded in the Spark connector. The exception gets thrown because the driver is not able to check the permissions of the `cassandra` superuser since not enough nodes are available to satisfy the authorisation request.

When authenticating with the default `cassandra` superuser role, [Cassandra performs the authentication/authorisation with a read consistency of `QUORUM`](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/operating/security.html#password-authentication). If not enough replicas of the `system_auth` keyspace are available for the `QUORUM` read then the authentication/authorisation operation will fail.

Our general recommendation is to only use the default `cassandra` superuser once to setup other admin and service roles. Once you have setup another superuser account, we recommend disabling the default `cassandra` superuser and never use it again for security reasons.

All the other roles (other than the default `cassandra` superuser) will authenticate with a consistency of `LOCAL_ONE`, even for superuser accounts.

The underlying issue apart from the incorrect use of the default `cassandra` superuser is that the nodes in the cluster become unresponsive/unavailable and the likely cause is that they are getting overloaded so authentication/authorisation fails.

Even if you switch to a regular service role which authenticates with `LOCAL_ONE`, you still have the problem with overloaded nodes so you should address that by reviewing the capacity of your cluster, possibly add more nodes. Cheers!